# getting "Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException" when running code sample

Tags: android, json

Help:
I'm using Android Studio and trying to work with a code sample from

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html
Code sample follows

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

String json  = "{"
  + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\", "
  + "  \"locations\": [ 94043, 90210 ] "
  + "}";

  JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
  // TBD - String query = object.getString("query");
  // TBD - JSONArray locations = object.getJSONArray("locations");
```

and as I enter these lines, Studio red lines 
  **new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();**

The error msg I get when I hover the cursor over the line is
  *"Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException"*

Any ideas or comments on what is causing this error would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either throw that exception or catch and handle it.

For example, catching the exception would mean:

```
try{
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
}catch(JSONException e){
    // Recovery
}
```

Throwing the exception would mean:

```
private void doSomething() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException*  means it is prone to **JSONException** . Android Studio is asking you to handle this possible exception by,

```
try {
     JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
} catch (JSONException ignored) {
  ignored.printStackTrace(); //now it is in log 
}
```

This will fix the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, which was resolved by adding below Maven dependency/ latest version of org.json:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20171018</version>
</dependency>
```